# Internal categories in an endofunctor category

Tags: ct.category-theory

Here we see the definition of an [internal category in a monoidal category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category+in+a+monoidal+category).  We also know that endofunctor categories support a monoidal product which is actually functor composition.  It is the case that a monoid in an endofunctor category is a monad, and so it makes sense that a comonoid is a comonad.  We could take the route that an internal category here is a monad on the category of internal comonoids.  It also looks to me like, if there is a comonad that is also a monad, we are done, we have an internal category.  Does this make sense? Is it the case that if we have Frobenius monads (a monad that can be turned into a comonad) these are the internal categories?

Comment: I think the problem with such monoidal structures is that they generally do not preserve equalisers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there was a bit of truth to this question.  [Here we see Spivak defining](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.01894) Categories as comonoids in the monoidal category $(Poly, \circ, y)$, section 2.5.  As I point out, comonoids in an endofunctor category are comonads.  I would guess that if you add a monad structure to your comonoids, you still have a category, but you have extra structure.  It would be interesting to know what extra stuff you are endowing the category with if you add monad structure.